# Check if Cloud Task Queue is empty

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api, google-cloud-tasks

I'm working on a project with a Node.js backend. It has a Cloud Task queue component and it creates hundreds of tasks. I need to run something once all the tasks are completed. I've been pouring over the Cloud Task queue documentation and searching online. However, I haven't found any documentation on how exactly to do this. All I need to know is how to determine if the task queue is empty. If it's empty after adding tasks, then the tasks are considered to be all completed.

My Cloud Task queue client is initialized like so:
`const client = new CloudTasksClient()`

Edit:

I wanted to note some documentation I found here that seems to indicate it might provide what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to implement it, I don't see any examples. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2#google.cloud.tasks.v2.ListTasksResponse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/list) on how to list the tasks in a queue. Take note that this sample uses Application Default Credentials for authentication so you need to be logged in on gcloud CLI.

Also another [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/listQueues.js). This example is about listing queues but it is also applicable to list tasks by using `client.listTasks()`.

I tested this code and it worked:

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

async function main () {
  const request = {
    parent: 'projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/REGION/queues/QUEUE-NAME', 
  };

  const [tasklist] = await client.listTasks(request);

  if (tasklist.length > 0) {
    console.log('Tasks:');
    tasklist.forEach(tasklist => {
      console.log(`  ${tasklist.name}`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('No tasks found on queue!');
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that documentation sample. However, it calls a line of code (as mentioned in your quoted code) that says:

`const cloudtasks = google.cloudtasks('v2');`

but I instantiate it like:

`const client = new CloudTasksClient()`

so, how do you adapt the first line of code to work based on that difference?

Comment: Updated answer.